# How to get the row of the last insert on Oracle using PDO?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo

I need to get the last row that I inserted using PDO in PHP. I've been searching and I've found PDO::lastInsertId but it doesn't work on Oracle.

What alternatives I have? Other ways to do that? I think to get the current value of the sequence (in that table I use a sequence to increment the ID) using PDO but I don't know if I can.

**Update 1:**

Here's my code.

```
static function insertarProveedor($name, $address, $phone, $email) {
    $con = conexionBD();
    try {
        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO Proveedores (NOMBRE, DIRECCION, TELEFONO, EMAIL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                        RETURNING OID_PROVEEDOR INTO :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $nombre);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $direccion);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $telefono);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $correo);
        $stmt->bindParam('OID_PROVEEDOR', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 8);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error".$e->GetMessage();
    }
    return $id;
}
```

I got the following message error:

> ErrorSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and
>   positional parameters
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\Gestor\include\inserciones.inc on line 43

The line 43 is `return $id;`

Comment: Code after Update 1 is correct but you have mismatched variable names, so SQL value of OID_PROVEEDOR trying to store as variable :id, and bindParam trying to attach PHP var $id as stored var :OID_PROVEEDOR

Answer (score 2):

you can use the oracle specific `returning id into var` method

```
$query = "INSERT INTO employees (name) VALUES ('Jones') RETURNING employee_no INTO     :employee_no";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam('employee_no', $employee_no, PDO::PARAM_INT, 8);
$stmt->execute();
```

Then the `$employee_no` will have the last id.

Comment: I added those code lines but what I got is an error message. Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to first retrieve the next value from the sequence and then use it in the insert statement.